# Using variables in gnuplot binary file plotting

Tags: variables, gnuplot, record, binaryfiles

I am plotting direct access binary files output from my simulations using gnuplot and want to write a simple generic script that will plot the files without me having to edit the file a lot. Here is what I want to do:

```
nx=real(system(sprintf("command to find nx")))
dx=real(system(sprintf("command to find dx")))
plot 'Fvy.dat' binary format="%double" record=nx skip=0*nx u ($0*dx):1 w l t '{/Symbol d}vy'
similar plotting multiple times
```

Now the problem is that the above command gives me an error

```
gnuplot> plot 'Fvy.dat' binary format="%double" record=nx skip=0*nx u ($0*0.025):1 w l t '{/Symbol d}vy'
                                                   ^
     ';' expected
```

If I use the number directly, e.g.

```
plot 'Fvy.dat' binary format="%double" record=128 skip=0*nx u ($0*dx):1 w l t '{/Symbol d}vy'
```

it works fine. The only place where the trouble lies is the record command. skip command takes  nx as an argument easily. Does anyone have an idea how to make record accept a variable?

Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to test without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put parentheses around nx:

```
plot 'Fvy.dat' binary format="%double" record=(nx) skip=0*nx u ($0*0.025):1 w l t '{/Symbol d}vy'
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias! Could you also please explain the rationale behind it? Thanks!

Comment: It's more or less the same with the using argument. You can either say using 1:2 with fixed numbers or calculate a expression, but then you have to put in parantheses like using ($1*2):(sin($2)).